# Why does Inuyasha stop using Blades of Blood after the first few episodes

Tags: inuyasha

I noticed that Inuyasha used Blades of Blood several times in the first few episodes of season 1, but then quits using it. I'm up to the beginning of season 3 now and he has not used the move in any of those episodes nor in *Affecions Touching Across Time*. Is there any explanation why? Both in-universe and out of universe explanations would be acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

After acquiring *Tessaiga*, Inuyasha no longer needed to rely on his more basic attacks unless he was without his signature weapon and otherwise out of options.

Additionally, Blades of Blood would require him to be previously injured, since it was an attack based on his own blood.  As time progressed, Inuyasha found himself in fewer situations where that attack would be viable, due to him improving as a swordsman, and having a group of friends to help fight certain *yokai* (whereas in the past, he did that all on his own).